# FileNotFound Exception when deleting existing file

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

I am making an application with Avalonia UI that can create and delete text files from a UI. I have a bug in my application that after a file is created in the UI if i try to delete the file I get a FileNotFound exception.  If i stop and start the application it loads the file and it successfully deletes the file.

I have verified that the text file is present in the output folder (and UI) when the save method is executed,

The file is created here in this method after a button press to "Save"

```
public void SaveNote()
{
    FileService.SaveToFile(new NoteModel(this.Filename, this.Content));
    OnNoteSaved(this);
}
```

FileService saves the file like so

```
public static void SaveToFile(NoteModel note)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(saveDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDirectory);
    }
    try
    {
        if(!File.Exists(note.Filename))
        {
            string filepath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, note.Filename);
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, note.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(note.Filename, note.Content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error saving file: {note.Filename}\nMessage: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

in a similar way to the save method, the call to delete the file is called here

```
public void DeleteNote()
{
    FileService.DeleteFile(new NoteModel(this.Filename, this.Content));
    OnNoteDeleted(this);
}
```

And the delete method in FileService is below

```
public static void DeleteFile(NoteModel note)
{
    if(Directory.Exists(saveDirectory))
    {
        try
        {
            if(File.Exists(note.Filename))
            {
                File.Delete(note.Filename);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException($"File not found: {note.Filename}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error deleting file: {note.Filename}\nMessage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException($"No Save Directory Found: {saveDirectory}");
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown in the catch block of DeleteFile shown below. When the application is restarted, the can be successfully deleted

```
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error deleting file: {note.Filename}\nMessage: {ex.Message}");
        }
```

Comment: GenericUser's answer seems to be the likely solution, but I wanted to add, consider a design that uses System.IO.FileInfo instead.  It's a more object oriented approach than System.IO.File and can prevent bugs like the one you discovered here because the path is created once and the FileInfo object is stored and used for all operations on that file until it's removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you construct the file path when creating the file, `string filepath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, note.Filename);`. However, in your delete method you are passing the file name only.

You should update your delete method to also create a file path similar to how you did in the create method. Then pass this into the delete method. See here for documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-8.0